# JQuery Drag and Drop features with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery, database, drag-and-drop

Hey I wanna save the order of my list to the sql server database in jquery drag & drop using asp.net c#.

How can I do this?

Comment: I wrote a similar article on this [Reorder list using jQuery and ASP.NET](http://codeasp.net/articles/asp-net/228/reorder-list-using-jquery-and-asp-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI has an event every time the user makes a drop, in that event you make a ajax request with the order of the elements to your server. There you save the order of the elements to your sql server.

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({
   drop: function(event, ui) { 
       $.ajax({...})
   }
});
```

I dont know Asp.net C#, but saving something in the server side to the database should be the easy part.