# Conversion from Coldfusion to Asp.net (Drag and Drop Functionality)

Tags: asp.net, coldfusion

I have Coldfusion web application that has a CF query from a database table. This data is displayed in an HTML table with a checkbox beside each data item and an associated picture. There is Jquery functionality on the page so that the items can be re-arranged in the table based on the users preference. After the user finishes with their re-arrangement, it is re-displayed without the checkboxes for sending as an email. Note I did not write this application myself but inherited it...

I need to transfer this functionality to a asp.net C# web application but i am at a crossroads on how to proceed. I've looked at telerik controls and others but none appear to fit the functionality i need. Any solid suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to handle rendering of the table yourself. If you're using asp.net webforms, this can be done with a custom server control. If you're using asp.net mvc (which I suggest as MVC matches the coldfusion development model a bit closer than webforms), then it's much simpler and you can just do so in the view.

Once you are rendering the grid yourself, then it's simple to apply the jquery functionality on the client-side.

Without more info about what you can or can't do, it's a bit difficult to offer any more guidance. But you did only ask for suggestions :-)

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net doesn't mean you need to use a library control built for .net. jQuery is powerful enough today, and it's not tied to any back end technology.

So, that being said, I would still go with jQuery and back it up with RESTful request using webservices with WebForms or controllers with MVC.

Have a look at this: [JQuery Drag and Drop features with ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106018/jquery-drag-and-drop-features-with-asp-net)

Comment: Finally got back to this. I read the article and have been able to implement it! However i need to have a two (2) column list which displays 6 items on one side and 6 on the other. Any suggestions?